# Is there a variable mass Verlete like integration algorithm?

Tags: classical-mechanics, computational-physics, integration, simulations, celestial-mechanics

I'm currently modeling the explosion of a star. For my simulation, I use a Verlete like integration algorithm. This is quite common in celestial mechanics modeling. The thing is that now that I have to account for mass change I don't know if the algorithm is still valid. The Newtons second law says
\begin{equation}
    F=m\frac{d^2X}{dt^2}+V\frac{dm}{dt}
\end{equation}
The typical Verlete like algorithm is
\begin{equation}
    V+=\frac{dV}{dt}\cdot dt
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    X+=\frac{dX}{dt}\cdot dt
\end{equation}
Some of them multiply by some other constant and there are many variations. So the question is if I take into account mass variation the algorithm becomes something like this?
\begin{equation}
    V+=\frac{dV}{dt}\cdot dt+\frac{V}{m}\frac{dm}{dt}\cdot dt
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    X+=\frac{dX}{dt}\cdot dt
\end{equation}
Is this a valid approach? Or the algorithm stays the same?

Comment: If $V=dx/dt$ and $X=x$, I am not sure your Newton's second law for variable mass system is correct ?

Comment: @VincentFraticelli. Well, the general Newton 2 law is dp/dt where p=vm is the momentum.  And yes, I missed out on the capital letter, Ill correct it.

Comment: This is your acceleration $a=\dfrac{F}{m}=\dfrac{dV}{dt}+\dfrac{V}{m} \dfrac{dm}{dt}$

Comment: The position is $\begin{aligned}x_{1}=x_{0}+v_{0}\Delta t+\dfrac{1}{2}a_{0}\Delta t^{2}\\
x_{n+1}=2x_{n}-x_{n-1}+a_{n}\Delta t^{2}\end{aligned}$

Comment: @Eli . So, what I have to do is just change the acceleration term?

Comment: @PM2Ring. Well actually Im using a 4th order algorithm. Its called PEFRL. You can find it in this article https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0110585.pdf in equation 22

Comment: For an open system of varying mass, I believe your equation is not correct. For example, for a rocket in space you would find $mdv/dt=-(dm/dt)v$ what is wrong.
It is necessary to use the formalism of open systems which takes into account the flow rates of momentum through the surface of the system.

Comment: Ah, ok. It looks like PEFRL is a refinement of Forest-Ruth, Yoshida, and Suzuki schemes (which are all closely related).

Comment: @CarlosAndrésdelValle first you need to obtain the velocity $V_{n+1}=\dfrac{x_{n+1}-x_{n}}{\Delta t}$ then the mass $m(t)$ from here you get the acceleration $a_n$

Comment: Why mangling names? **Verlete $\rightarrow$ Verlet**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting your first equation, I rewrite by shifting $dV/dt$ to the left hand side:
\begin{align}
    F&=m\frac{d V}{dt}+V\frac{dm}{dt}\\
    \frac{d V}{dt} &= \frac{F}{m} - \frac{V}{m}\frac{dm}{dt}
\end{align}

Therefore,

\begin{align}
  V+ = \frac{d V}{dt} dt &= \frac{F}{m} dt - \frac{V}{m}\frac{dm}{dt} dt\\
&= \frac{F}{m} dt - V\frac{d (\ln m)}{dt} dt
\end{align}

In the rocket motion, the second term is a positive acceleration, since the mass changing rate $\frac{dm}{dt}$ is negative.

**But this is only valid for case of no explosion.** That means the separated part $dm$ is of a same velocity with the main body $m(t)$. For case of internal explosion, there is a extra expelling force which is not taking into account in the $
\frac{d(m(t)v(t))}{dt}$ term. You have to refer to answer of Elis for internal explosion.

For extra expelling force or even not in the same direction, we have to start from the conservation of momentum:

Momentum before separation:
$$
\vec P(t) = m(t) \vec V(t).
$$

Momentum after separation:
\begin{align}
\vec P(t+\Delta t) &= m(t+\Delta t) \vec V(t+\Delta t) + \Delta m \left( \vec U(t)+ \vec V(t) \right)\\
&\approx m(t) \vec V(t) - \Delta m \vec V(t) + m(t) \Delta \vec{V} +\Delta m \left( \vec U(t)+ \vec V(t) \right) \\
&=  m(t) \vec V(t) + m(t) \Delta \vec{V} +\Delta m \, \vec U(t) 
\end{align}
Where $\Delta m = - \frac{dm}{dt} \Delta t$, and $\vec U$ is the velocity of the separated part w.r.t to the reference frame of the mass moving object, therefore the velocity of the separated w.r.t the ground is $\vec U(t) + \vec V(t)$. For linear rocket motion $\vec U(t)$ is in the opposite direction of $\vec V$.

For the conservation of momentum, $ P(t+\Delta t) - \vec P(t) = \vec F \Delta t$, we then have:
$$
    m(t)\Delta \vec V(t) + \Delta m\, \vec U(t) = \vec F \Delta t.
$$
recall that $\Delta m = -\frac{dm}{dt} \Delta t$. We than have the differential form:
\begin{align}
   & m(t) \Delta \vec V(t) -\frac{dm}{dt}  \Delta t\, \vec U(t) = \vec F \Delta t.\\
& \Delta \vec V(t) =\left(  \frac{\vec F}{m}  + \frac{d (\ln m)}{dt} \vec U(t) \right)\Delta t
\end{align}

This renders:
$$
  \vec V += \left( \frac{\vec F}{m}  + \frac{d (\ln m)}{dt} \vec U(t) \right)\Delta t.
$$

This may include the cases of explosion and side impact motion. For rocket motion. we consider $\vec U(t) = \vec U_0$ is a constant. But for mass attaching problem, it may be more appropriate to consider $\vec U(t) + \vec V(t)$ is a constant.

Comment: why do you put an ln(m) in the derivative? Can you tell me a bit more about the expel force and give me some starting reference, please?  What happens in the case the mass loss is not in the direction of movement, for example, a sphere that losses or gains a chunk, does your equation still hold?

Comment: The $\ln m$ has no big deal. It is written in this form in the rocket motion for  integration. I will add some text in the answer for extra expel force and bending motion.

Answer (score 1):

This is the rocket  equation with out external force

$$\frac{dv}{dt}=(u-v(t))\,\frac{\frac{dm}{dt}}{m(t)}$$

- v rocket velocity
- u exhaust velocity
- m rocket mass

I assume that the reduction of the Rocket mass is according to this function

$$m(t)= m_s+(m_s+m_0)\,e^{-\frac{t}{T}}$$

- $m_0~$ rocket  mass at t=0
- $m_s~$ rocket  mass at the final time
- $T~$ reduction time constant

**The Verlet Integration**

$$x_{n+1}=2\,x_n-x_{n-1}+a_n\,dt^2\quad~,n=2..N\\
x_1=x_0+v_0\,dt+\frac 12 a_0\,dt$$
where $~x_0~,v_0~$ are the initial conditions and

$$a_n=(u-v_n)\,\frac{dm(t_n)}{m(t_n)}\\
v_n=\frac{x_n-x_{n-1}}{dt}\\
m(t_n)=m_s+(m_s+m_0)\,e^{-\frac{t_n}{T}}\\
dm(t_n)=\frac{m_0-m_s}{T}\,e^{-\frac{t_n}{T}}\\
t_n=n\,dt
$$

- $t_n$ discrete time
- $dt$ step size
- $a_n~$ rocket acceleration
- $v_n~$ rocket velocity

**Simulation**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking how the algorithm will be with a variable mass particle.

Comment: @CarlosAndrésdelValle this is new answer for rocket equation